# Why does Python change the value of an integer when there is a 0 in front of it?

Tags: python, integer, python-2.x

I implemented a function converting an integer number to its representation as a string `intToStr()` (code below).

For testing I've passed in some values and observed an unexpected output:

```
print intToStr( 1223) # prints 1223 as expected
print intToStr(01223) # prints  659, surprisingly
```

Now, I've tried to debug it, and the the integer I've passed in has indeed turned out to be `659`.

Why does this happen and how can I get python to ignore leading zeros of the integer literal?

---

Here's the code for my function:

```
def intToStr(i):
    digits = '0123456789'
    if i == 0:
        return 0
    result = ""
    while i > 0:
        result = digits[i%10] + result
        i /= 10
    return result
```

Comment: use `lstrip('0')` to remove the '0's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said that's because of octal numbers. But I strongly suggest you to change your function to:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> force_decimal = partial(int, base=10)
>>> force_decimal("01")
1
>>> force_decimal("0102301")
102301
```

This way you will explicitly force the conversion to base 10. And int wont be inferring it for you.

Comment: I did not know this, thanks for this piece of information! :) You're the only person who said this! :)

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: but since you were converting *from int to str* it wasn't the most obvious thing to advice, since this is conversion *from str to int* instead. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I know that, I just wanted to know if there was a way of doing it. You never know what you need.

Answer (score 9):

An integer literal starting with a 0 is interpreted as an [octal number, base 8](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-and-long-integer-literals):

```
>>> 01223
659
```

This has been changed in Python 3, where integers with a leading 0 are considered errors:

```
>>> 01223
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    01223
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> 0o1223
659
```

You should never specify an integer literal with leading zeros; if you meant to specify an octal number, use `0o` to start it, otherwise strip those zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers that start with a `0` are interpreted as [octal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).
If it starts with `0x` it's hexa decimal.

Answer (score 0):

A leading zero causes Python to interpret your number as octal (base-8).

To strip out the zeros (assuming num is a string), do:

```
num.lstrip("0")
```